# How to get visible nodes with Visjs

Tags: vis.js

I have this large network created with `vis-network`:

[image: full network]

When clicking on the nodes I create clusters. For example if I click on the 2 green boxes the result is:

[image: network with clusters]

In this new view I have two regular nodes ("Program #3289" and "Task #7300") and two clusters ("Project #3415" and "Project #3416") that contain their children.

If I use `dataset.get()` it returns all my 106 initial nodes.
If I use `network.body.nodes` it returns all my 106 initial nodes + my two clusters.

What I want: a way to only get the visible nodes in my network. In that case, I should get only 2 regular nodes and 2 clusters.

Did I miss a function that permits to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with the below solution:

```js
var visibleNodes = [];  
for (var nodeId in visNetwork.body.nodes) {
  // we check if the node is inside a cluster
  if (!visNetwork.clustering.clusteredNodes[nodeId]) {
    visibleNodes.push(nodeId)
  }
}
```